# Can I set a MySQL event schedule using phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, events, phpmyadmin, mysql-event

I want to increment a field on the first minute of every day, and then once it hits a certain value, set the value to 1. I would like to do this directly in MySQL, but preferably through phpMyAdmin.

I am aware of the [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events.html), and so I'm looking for a way to use and manage it through phpMyAdmin. Is this possible?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is.. Just issue appropriate `CREATE EVENT` SQL from SQL box.

However: your MySQL server needs to have event scheduler enabled AND have `EVENT` privileges for the database user.

Calling `SELECT @@event_scheduler;` will tell you if the scheduler is available and enabled.

To enable event scheduler if it's disabled try calling `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler := 1;`
You need the `SUPER` privilege for this to succeed.

Comment: Great, also just as an aside, you need MySQL 5.1 or greater to use this feature.

Comment: Yup. SELECT @@event_scheduler; will raise an error in lower versions.

Answer (score 25):

Select query browser in phpmyadmin run the query to ON event scheduler

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Only super privilege user can do this. To grand privilege to user by

```
GRANT EVENT ON myschema.* TO jon@ghidora;
```

Check event_sheduler status ON or OFF by

```
SELECT @@event_scheduler;
```

If status is ON go ahead for create event

```
CREATE EVENT e_store_ts
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 10 SECOND
    DO
      INSERT INTO myschema.mytable VALUES (UNIX_TIMESTAMP());
```

To see the events that created

```
SHOW EVENTS;
```

Comment: Hello you example is really greate but how about update data with every one month especially first date in month, i hvae been teested your query is really great, but change as needed it doesn't work, please have see images is here http://prntscr.com/a2ncgl

Answer (score 3):

If doing this on Amazon RDS you need to edit the parameter group to add `EVENT_SCHEDULER = ON`. One easy way to do this is via a free Rightscale account.